# computer randomly restarting. both in game and out of game

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, nvidia-geforce

first my specs are.

AMD Phenom II x4 955 processor 3.2ghz
20gb ddr3 ram
4Gb Nvidia Geforce GTX 770
850w Corsair tx850w psu
Gigabyte ud3 mobo
Windows 7 professional

I recently uprgraded my vid card to gtx770 and upgraded my psu to the 850w thats in it now. i did a reformat with the installation of the new gpu and psu and started fresh and only have a couple programs installed (diablo3, nvidia control panel, wow, and steam). all drivers are up to date and everything is hooked up correctly.

the problem is it will randomly shut down. no blue screen. just turns itself straight off and reboots after a couple seconds. occasionally i will have to unplug the power cable from the psu for a few minutes then reconnect and it will start up. it seems pretty random. sometimes it does it when my pc is just sitting there on the home screen. and sometimes it does it during games. and sometimes it doesnt do it for days at a time. i noticed the psu felt hot so i put an extra fan blowing straight onto both the psu and gpu and neither feel overly hot after it shuts down now.

could it just be that it is a psu problem. the psu was taken from another machine but wasnt having this problem in that machine. i have seen a few articles online about gtx770 doing the same thing. but i havent found any answers or solutions. any help will be appreciated. im sure the 850w is enough to power my machine, im just stumped and ran out of ideas to fix it. i have even returned the video card for another thinking it might have been an issue with that particular card, but still gettin the same problem.

Comment: i did the eventvwr.msc and it says error  and has the time/date when i use the 6008 command in the filter. says "The previous system shutdown at 4:30:32 PM on 8/20/2014 was unexpected." what information do u need? it says the same for every unexpected shutdown. i can go into details and it has a string of numbers and letters beginning DE07080003001400100001E .... and goes on awhile. am i looking in the right place?

Comment: You're looking in the right place; That message means that something on the hardware level cut off power without notifying windows.

Answer (score 3):

Install [GPU-Z](http://www.techpowerup.com/gpuz/) and [Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) to monitor your temperatures, because it sounds like you have an overheating problem. Keep them on-screen so you can see what the temperatures are; check frequently while doing whatever you normally do to cause the problem.

The motherboard will kill power to the system if your GPU reaches **95C** (According to the specs for the GTX770), or if the CPU reaches the `Tj Max` value listed in CoreTemp.

If the temperatures are getting anywhere near these values, you should start with cleaning dust out of the system. Make sure fans are working and aren't clogged. Compressed air is very useful for this (but hold fans so that they don't spin wildly when using compressed air on them - this can damage them if you don't!)

If you've cleaned out the case and components, and you're not in the middle of the Sahara, and there seems to be good airflow coming out the exhausts for the GPU, then you may need to look at reseating the heatsinks/coolers for the GPU and CPU. If you're unfamiliar with this and don't trust yourself, find a friend that knows how, or take it to your local tech shop and tell them that your system is overheating and that you think the 's heatsink needs to be reseated.

---

Given that you've swapped out GPUs, and the fact that it happens both when you're playing games and when you're not, I suspect that it's the CPU that is overheating. It's also possible that the motherboard is overheating, or it has a fault.

Comment: just took the case apart. minimum amount of dust with nothing clogging the fan. i know how to heatsink the cpu. i did it when i installed it 2 years ago and it ran fine. is it possible the heatsink fluid isnt working now? i can get another tube of it and clean the old out and redo it. im not sure how to do the gpu tho. its a pci-express gtx770 about a month old. 2nd one ive installed in 2 months. im downloading the gpu-z and core temp programs now so ill check the temps. they dont feel hot to the touch but i guess it could be internal. ill repost once i get steady temp readings. thanks alot

Comment: ok been runnin a game and playing it hard highest that the gpu got up to was 51C and the core temp got up to 55C. the tj max is listed at 79C. it hasnt died either is there a way to check what the temperature level needs to be before it requires shutdown?

Comment: still getting an unexpected shutdown. both cpu and gpu temps are less then 50C.

Comment: @eric Hmmm, those temperatures sound fine, it's probably not the GPU or CPU overheating then. My next steps would be to swap out the CPU with a known good one, then the RAM, and finally the motherboard, one at a time, until the shutdowns stop.